# Use the same PHP session on two different folders on the same server

Tags: php, session

I have two folders on my webspace `Folder1` and `Folder2`. Both folders have PHP content in it. In `Folder1`'s `index.php` I'm setting a session variable which I want to be known in `Folder2`. I already searched for a solution and I also found something with `session_set_cookie_params()` - but it's not working. Here are the files I'm working with:

```
<?php

// index.php inside /blog/Folder1/

session_name('s');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'www.mydomain.de');
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');
session_start();
$_SESSION['auth_key'] = 'abc';
echo 'Key assigned';

?>
```

And my second file which is trying to access the already set session variable:

```
<?php

// index.php inside /blog/Folder2/

session_name('s');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'www.mydomain.de');
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');
session_start();

if($_SESSION['auth_key'] != 'abc')
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
}

// do more stuff ...

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Tom this is not right, the `session_set_cookie_params()` always comes before session starts, check the doc please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your php, but to debug this you need to understand this, for security reason http will not set cookie for top level domains, as a result you need to use second level domain as follow:

`session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.mydomain.de');`

you noticed I replaced `www.mydomain.de` by `.mydomain.de`

**A little more**

make sure you have the domains set up if they are not you can still use `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');` without indicating the subdomain index.

Comment: Thank you... That fixed it.